# Play framework groovy script parameters

Tags: groovy, parameters, playframework

I have a function in application doing the following

```
renderTemplate("Application/output.json", user);
```

Then in the json file

```
%{
  Application.renderJson(user)
  Application.getRatesAndPrint(user.format)
}%
```

The above states that "user" is null, when it is not, what's going on? by the way, I also tried the

```
renderArgs("user", user)
```

method, but the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that you can't render to the page you're trying to render from, which I think is a weakness, so this is what I am doing now:

```
%{
    def builder = new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder();
    def jsonString = new   StringBuffer().append(builder.create().toJson(user)).append('\n');

    def ratesUrl = new URL("http://stone01:8080/rateservice/conversions.json")
    def inStream = ratesUrl.openStream()
    def bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream))
    def sLine = ""
    while((sLine = bReader.readLine()) != null){
        jsonString.append(sLine).append('\n');
    }
    println(jsonString.toString())
}%
```